# How to add Music ON/OFF functionality button?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I include a Music ON/OFF functionality button in the bottom left corner of all wizard pages except the Finished page. And the music being active should stop only after the user hit Finish button.

[image]

```
    procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  // Welcome page
  // Hide the labels
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Visible := False;
  // Stretch image over whole page
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Width := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Parent.Width;

  begin with WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage do SetBounds(Parent.Left, Parent.Top, Parent.Width, Parent.Height);
  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Visible := False; end;

  // Finished page
  // Hide the labels
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Visible := False;
  // Stretch image over whole page
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Width := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Parent.Width;
end;

procedure AboutButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgBox('This is the about message!', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
  AboutButton : TNewButton;
begin
  // create an instance of the button and assign it to the local variable AboutButton
  AboutButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  // set the parent to the just created button control
  AboutButton.Parent := WizardForm;
  // adjust the position to the created button control; it gets the horizontal indent
  // by the right indent of the Cancel button; the vertical position as well as width
  // and height are the same as the Cancel button has
  AboutButton.Left := WizardForm.ClientWidth - WizardForm.CancelButton.Left -
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
  AboutButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
  AboutButton.Width := WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
  AboutButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
  // set its caption
  AboutButton.Caption := '&About';
  // and assign the AboutButtonOnClick method to the OnClick event of the button
  AboutButton.OnClick := @AboutButtonOnClick;
end;

procedure AboutButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgBox('This is the about message!', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

const
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD;
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: string; offset1: DWORD;
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: BOOL): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Free: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Free@files:bass.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  StreamHandle: HSTREAM;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    StreamHandle := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False,
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0,
      EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(StreamHandle, False);
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  BASS_Free;
end;

procedure AboutButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;

var
  // Global variable
  AboutButton: TNewButton;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // create an instance of the button and assign it to the global variable AboutButton
  Music ON\OFF  := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  ...
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // Hide button on Finished page
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    AboutButton.Visible := False;
  end;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create the button or how to start/stop the music or both (these are two separate topics)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a button on the bottom panel, see:
[How to create new About button in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30867416/850848)

---

For background music, see:
[Playing sound during an Inno Setup install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12359859/850848)

---

To stop music playback on button click, just call `DSStopMediaPlay` (Inno Media Player) from the `OnClick` handler.

```pascal
procedure AboutButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;
```

---

To hide the button on Finished page, you need to save a button reference to a global variable and set `.Visible` = `false` in [`CurPageChanged(wpFinished)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged):

```pascal
[Code]

var
  { Global variable }
  AboutButton: TNewButton;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { create an instance of the button and assign it to the global variable AboutButton }
  AboutButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  ...
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  { Hide button on Finished page }
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    AboutButton.Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, you want to name the variable `StopButton`, not `AboutButton`.

Comment: This is my iss script. I'm getting error duplicate identifier 'InitializeWizard'

Comment: I did all procedure as you demonstrated. I don't know pascal programming so plz help

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to download some .exe file from a random webpage just to get your .iss. Upload it elsewhere. Or just append the code to your question. Anyway, you probably have multiple `InitializeWizard` procedures in your code. Just merge the code between `begin` and `end` into one procedure. See [I have duplicated InitializeSetup in INNO SETUP how can i solve it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24040732/850848)

Comment: No I have uploaded my .iss file & it is in kb's

Comment: Anyway I'm trying again

Comment: Still couldn't make it right. Please Martin make the corrections in the iss over the link above. It's a very small file.

Comment: Got it. I didn't notice that grey checkbox below the download button.

Comment: Again, just take all the lines between `begin` and `end` of the second `InitializeWizard` procedure (starting with `// create an instance of the button ...`, ending with `... @AboutButtonOnClick;` and move that before the `end;` line of the first `InitializeWizard` procedure. And remove the rest of the second instance. Also the `AboutButton : TNewButton;` must be global, so add `var AboutButton : TNewButton;` just after the `[Code]`, as in my answer above.

Comment: You also have two instances of the `AboutButtonOnClick`, remove the first with `MsgBox`. You do not need that. + The procedure has to be defined before it is used, so before the `InitializeWizard`.

Comment: You use `DSStopMediaPlay` from (Inno Media Player) from the `AboutButtonOnClick`, yet you use the BASS library. That cannot work.

Comment: I see you have the global `AboutButton` variable at the end. Again it has to be defined before it is used, so before the `InitializeWizard` (the first one, the only one). And remove the third instance of `InitializeWizard` (with the `Music ON\OFF`).

Comment: Yeah I did. Now it says unknown identifier 'AboutButtonOnClick'

Comment: Brother I have told you I don't know pascal programming..I didn't understand this all. Please just edit my .iss, it would be highly appreciating.  Please..

Comment: It's the last thing I need to implement in my application setup

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We answer questions here.   I've covered the `AboutButtonOnClick` above.

Comment: Attach the code after the corrections you done already. The code you have attached still fails with `Duplicate identifier 'INITIALIZEWIZARD'`, not with `unknown identifier 'AboutButtonOnClick'`.

Comment: Actually I accidently closed the script without saving changes. So now this only where I'm...